# In Google Sheets, automatically update a data-validation field with default value when another field changes (and maintain data-validation dropdown)

Tags: google-sheets

I've created [this public Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i1B7znhEqTTlCLayKeyCbCXfpXYQFNCBq4CVJMK0dLg/edit?usp=sharing) to showcase our question

[image]

The focus is on `cell E3`. This is a data validation cell with the values in `A9:A17` as the options. Also key is `cell E2`, which is simply equal to `cell E1`, and `cell E1` which we manually update with one of the 5 team values `a,b,c,d,e` (in this dummy example at least). The `E1`, `E2` linking may be trivial, but it's how our real spreadsheet is setup.

We have a set of `default values` in the table `A1:B6` for each of the *"teams"*. Our question: when we change the value in `cell E1` (which also updates `E2`), is there anyway to automatically update the value in `cell E3` with the default color? For example, if we type `c` into `cell E1`, then `cell E3` updates with `green`. Keep in mind, what is key is that after the default value is somehow set, the data-validation still functions where we can change the value in `cell e3` to a different color if we so choose.

We have a strong preference for avoiding Apps Script if possible, preferring instead a solution that simply links up with the cells. Thanks!

**EDIT:** this question has nothing to do with the conditional formatting the colors. We only care about showing the text in `cell E3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without code, you can set one conditional formatting for each colour:

```
=IF(E3<>"",E3,VLOOKUP(E1,$A$2:$B$6,2))="red"
```

Created for three colours in a copy of your tab:

[image]

[image]

### Update

For achieving the value, you could create an auxiliary hidden column. In my example it is in orange, but you keep it hidden. The you insert this formula in E3 that will expand to F3 when it's not filled

```
={"",VLOOKUP( F1,A1:B6,2,0)}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: We don't want to conditionally format the color. We just want the text to show in the cell! I see how this was a misleading example using the `color` column, but it is only the text that we care about.

Comment: Updated answer looks good, using a 2nd cell makes sense. Thanks!